# Html.ActionLink() not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, string, view, encoding, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working with visual studio building a bookstore website for a class project and I am having trouble getting my strings to encode.

I basically print out the link to the details of a specific book

```
@Html.ActionLink(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title).ToString(), "Details", new { id = item.BookID })
```

With the title of the book (which is pulled straight from the database) contained as a parameter that is supposed to be displayed text.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title).ToString()
```

But the issue is my output on the front end looks like this

[image: This is my output]

How do I overcome this?

I have tried decoding to bytes then re-encoding, but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you get when you do this?

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", new { id = item.BookID })
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the property of your Title to return a HtmlString since your titles appear to be already html encoded.

Comment: Title is actually pulled from a field in the database.  The datatype is varchar so I shouldn't be having any trouble I don't think.

Comment: If the text already contains escaped characters you are basically double escaping them. Verify how the text is stored in the database.

Comment: The text goes into the database via stored procedure and in the database it appears to have the single quotes. But it does not appear that way when it is spit back out. I believe it has something to do with tostring()-ing it. There has to be someway to still get the link to show without using the html.actionlink method. Because I think that is my problem.